# Undefined reference while compile

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, reference, linker

I'm trying to addapt a binary into ARM procesor.
I have the source code, and I'm trying to do all the modifications in order to it can be compiled.

As I thought all was done, I try to compile it as the "makefile" said, but an error was throwed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTN4uMT.o: undefined reference to symbol 'RAND_bytes'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'RAND_bytes' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I can understand, I have to specify the "libcrypto.so.1.0.0" to the compilation code, but I have no idea of where I have to reference it.

The used command was:

```
sudo gcc -O3 -fexpensive-optimizations -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer foo1.cpp foo2.cpp foo3.cpp foo4.cpp foo5.cpp -lssl -o mybinary
```

Comment: Put it after the linking with `libssl`: `-lssl -lcrypto` (or possibly before: `-lcrypto -lssl`)

Comment: Works fine. Now I have no problem with "lcrypto", but I have a 482 line file full of "missed reference to '...'", so I think now I have to look after all this references and put it in the command... hehe. Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile your libraries with the arm-toolchain before linking it?

Comment: I just forgot to use "-lstdc++" library. That's all. Thanks both for answering